# make <div> tag stay, didn't move

Tags: css, html

How to, as the title suggests, make a div didn't move. So, when the user scroll our web, the content is moving but not the div-element. If let say the div-element I want to implement is a sidebar, how can I do that with only a CSS script? (or with HTML5 power).

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">
div.fixedDiv{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#yourdiv{
 position:absolute;
 left:100px;
 top:150px;
}
</style>

<div id="yourdiv">Hello I'm div</div>
```

Adjust the coordinates left and top as you desire.

Anyways you can see css positionings [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=absolute).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this... [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7GfT/)

Html

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="fixed"></div>
</div>​
```

Css..

```
.wrapper { position: relative; height: 1500px; background:red; }
.fixed { position: fixed; left:0; top:50; width:100px; height:100px; background: green; }
```